# Unable to run AppEngine Bigquery example

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to run the Bigquery example found in

```
python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python37/bigquery
```

I went to that folder and ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

From there I ran

```
python main.py
```

My localhost launches (http://localhost:8080).  However, when I go to that URL it says "This site can't be reached."  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this under the **main** function

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Note that this is only necessary for [deploying locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service#testing_your_web_service)